# How to get just directory name from HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I am trying to get the directory name from hdfs location using spark. I am getting the whole path to the directory instead of just the directory name.

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
val ls = fs.listStatus(new Path("/user/rev/raw_data"))
ls.foreach(x => println(x.getPath))
```

This gives me

> hdfs://localhost/user/rev/raw_data/191622-140
>
> hdfs://localhost/user/rev/raw_data/201025-001
>
> hdfs://localhost/user/rev/raw_data/201025-002
>
> hdfs://localhost/user/rev/raw_data/2065-5
>
> hdfs://localhost/user/rev/raw_data/223575-002

How can I just get the output as below (i.e. just the directory name)

> 191622-140
>
> 201025-001
>
> 201025-002
>
> 2065-5
>
> 223575-002

Comment: Note: Spark isn't necessary to read from HDFS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you work with `Path` objects when using `status.getPath`, you can simply use the [`getName`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.html) function on `Path` objects:

```
FileSystem
  .get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
  .listStatus(new Path("/user/rev/raw_data"))
  .filterNot(_.isFile)
  .foreach(status => println(status.getPath.getName))
```

which would print:

```
191622-140
201025-001
201025-002
2065-5
223575-002
```